# Using table columns in prepared statement parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc

My page has a dropdown list that let a user choose any search category like title, description and so forth. So I have this SQL statement:

```
select * from table where "selected value from dropdown list" = "searchform"
```

I would like to pass it to the prepared statement like this:

select * from table where ? = ?

Since my select statements have the same form, only the columns in the where clause are different, is there a way to do this without manually creating select statements for every column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is called dynamic sql.

```
DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 'select * from table where ' + @column + ' = ''' + @value + ''''
EXEC(@sql)
```

You must check if the column is of numeric type.
You should also be careful for sql injection. My example is a very simplistic one, so you have to do your own checks.

For instance use of [QUOTENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) would be useful:

```
DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 'select * from table where ' + QUOTENAME(@column) + ' = ''' + @value + ''''
EXEC(@sql)
```

The above examples are simply TSQL. In your prepared statement i think you could have the following:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("
    DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @sql = 'select * from table where ' + QUOTENAME(?) + ' = ? '
    EXEC(@sql)
");
pstm.setString(1,columnName);
pstm.setString(2,filterValue);
```

Unfortunately i am not familiar with JAVA, so i have not tested this. I think it worths a try though.

The above `@sql` variable will produce a statement like :

```
select * from table where [columnname] = filtervalue
```

`columnname` wrapped with brackets will help against SQL injection.

Comment: I should put this in the prepared statement?

Comment: Check my edit. I am not familiar with java so this could be wrong. I just found that in the documentation on how to use prepared statement. One other problem is that you wouldn't know what to pass in the second param, but i guess you could have a switch or something.